# PYTHON 3: Pig Latin, again, but hear me out

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, latin

Before you say there are other threads, trust me I have read them all and I have found them not helpful because I implimented my code different, and I have been doing it myself from the start.  Not looking for a freebie but some actual help.

My code below shows I can open a file to be translated into Pig Latin, strip it of all punctuation and useless numbers, and return a list of the words in the file.  The stipulation is I only have to translate words.  If the word begins with a vowel, add "ay" to the end.  If the word starts with a consonant, remove the first letter from the word, add it to the end of the word and add "ay" to the end.

ie:  word = "ordway:
and orange = "orangeay"

The Code:

```
import re
import nltk

def usr_name_file():
    """
        Function:  Gets name of file to translate
        Parameter: n/a
        Returns: name of file to open 
    """
    nameFile = input('\nEnter the filename to translate into Piglatin >>>')

    return nameFile

def validate_name(nameFile):
    """
        Function:  Validates the existance of the usr file
        Parameter: Name of file input by usr
        Returns: Error if file not found, none if file found
    """
    try:
        inputFile= open(nameFile, 'r')
        inputFile.close()
    except IOError:
        print('Error: File not found in this directory.\nTry again.\n')

    return

def open_named_file(nameFile):
    """
        Function:  
        Parameter:
        Returns:
    """
    with open(nameFile, 'r') as readFile:
        data = readFile.read()
        print(data)         # import re makes this easier
        words_list = re.findall(r"[\w']+", data)  # extract punctuation
        sans_numbers = [x for x in words_list if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == 
                                                   '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]  

    return sans_numbers


def translate(list):     # Help Here Please!
    """
        Function:  Takes in word and translates into piglatin
        Parameter:  Word
        Returns:  Translated word
    """

    return

def main():

    x = usr_name_file()
    validate_name(x)
    WordsList = open_named_file(x)
    print(WordsList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gets me to where I am now, a list of words in the file, no punc.
The unfinished translate() function is where I have some difficulty.  Below is the pseudo code of what I want it to do:

```
def translate(list):
    for vowel_word, consonant_word in list:
        if the word starts with a vowel, add "ay" to the end
        if the word starts with a consonant, replace the first letter to the
        end and add "ay"
    return translated_list
```

The idea is that for the list of words I pass to the translate function, I want it to go in and make a new list of words in the same order, but translated.  The only way I know how to do it now is to create a list of vowel words and a list of consonant words, but if i do that I think it will be difficult to write a new file with the translated sentences using .write()  I know how to write the new file code, so all I need help on is this function.  Full disclosure this is for HW but as you can see I am not asking for a freebie, just a little help with this function, which is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe some lambda functions with map, reduce, or something like that?

Comment: I would suggest investigating the `str.startswith()` method.

Comment: sure I thought of that too, but my real issue is not knowing how to go into my list of words and based off of two if statements append one new list

Comment: What about starting with two or more consonants?  start->artstay, through->oughthray.  What about words like "my" or "why"?

Comment: Yes I am modifying the consonant list for this as well

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Start with empty translated list.
- Iterate the word list, for each word:

  - Find the index of the first vowel.
  - If it is zero, add 'way'
  - If it is non-zero, use string slicing, e.g. word[i:]+word[:i]+'ay'
  - Append new word to translated list.

Comment: HAHA!  Thats what I just did and it works too.  Now I am writing the function that puts all back into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's still looking at this, here's a solution (where 'par' in the first line is the block of text you're dealing with):

```
word_list = par.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)

def par_pig_short():

new_par = []

vowel_list = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

for word in word_list:      

    for char in word: 
        if char in vowel_list: 
            i = word.index(char)

    sol = word[i:] + word[:i] + 'ay'
    new_par.append(sol.lower())

final_new_par = ' '.join(new_par)    

return final_new_par
```